# Python: Getting PID of process in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, subprocess

I want to run Firefox from python and get PID of Firefox to kill it later. I'm trying to use

```
process = subprocess.Popen([self.config['exec'], *self.config['args']])
```

But PID which i got not exist and i can't kill it later. Do you have any ideas why it happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Might be that the process dies right after spawning which might happen if it got some error. Try checking the logs in `process.stdout` & `process.stderr`

Comment: Many programs will simply activate an existing instance of the program; create a new window or tab; and exit. If `process.kill()` fails, then whatever instance of Firefox that's still running is not your problem, and killing it is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Also, use the object's `kill` or `terminate` method. Don't kill by PID. The `Popen` instance has a handle for the process, and the handle value is guaranteed to always refer to that process object until the handle is closed. A PID, on the other hand, may be reassigned to another process as soon as the previous process is reaped by the kernel process manager, so killing by PID may terminate an unrelated process.

Comment: I tried to read stdout and stderr but they are empty. Maybe there is other way to run external app let python to work and after it finish close app in background?